# Langchain RetrievalQAChain providing the correct answer despite of 0 docs returned from the vector database

Tags: langchain, langchain-js

I thought RetrievalQAChain will only reply based on the documents returned from the database. My prompt explicitly says, don't reply if you don't know the answer. 0 documents were returned from my vector database and I hopping it would say I don't know the answer but instead I got the correct response. I think CHATGPT is using it's own knowledge to answer the question even though 0 documents were added in the context. Am I missing something here.

After seeing this, even if there are a few relevant documents in the prompttemplate, how do we know CHATGPT used those to generate a response or replied based on its own knowledge.

```js
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const prompt = new PromptTemplate({
      template:
        "Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.\n\nContext: {context}\n\nQuestion: {question}\nHelpful Answer:",
      inputVariables: ["context", "question"],
    });


    {/*Rest of the code */}
    const vectorStoreRetriever = vectorStore.asRetriever(5);

    console.log(
      "vectorStoreRetriever",
      await vectorStoreRetriever._getRelevantDocuments(message)
    );

    const model = new OpenAI({
      streaming: true,
      temperature: 0,
      timeout: 60000,
    });
    // Create a chain that uses the OpenAI LLM and HNSWLib vector store.
    const chain = new RetrievalQAChain({
      combineDocumentsChain: loadQAStuffChain(model, { prompt }),
      retriever: vectorStore.asRetriever(),
    });

    const results = await chain.call({
      query: "What is NextJs",
    });

    // return NextResponse.json({ splitDocuments });
    return NextResponse.json({ results });
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log(e);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: e.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: I have the same situation and looking for an answer. Did you manage to solve this behaviour ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It is difficult to say of ChatGPT is using its own knowledge to answer user question but if you get 0 documents from your vector database for the asked question, you don't have to call LLM model and return the custom response "I don't know.".

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because OpenAI model has already had the knowledge of NextJs, so that's why even the retriever got nothing, the model was still able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Append below lines of prompt to your existing prompt.

"""
Don't justify your answers. Don't give information not mentioned in the CONTEXT INFORMATION. If the answer is not in the context, say the words
"Sorry, I am unable to answer your question with the information available to me"
"""

Answer (score 0):

use correct langchain retriever and put the similarity threshold like score or top N results criteria after that it will your RAG bot will not go beyond the given document.

for more details read langchain different retriever -
https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains